# How to know the return address of a function?

Tags: c

In my code, control is jumping from an interrupt service routine to some X function. After executing that X function, it's doing reset because it doesn't know to where it should return. Can you please tell me the what registers I need to take care of when jumping from interrupt service routine to function X ?

**Scenario:**

```
Function m() {
    Function x();
}

Function x() {
    Step1:
    Step2:call Function Y();
    Step3: 
}

Function y() {
    Step1:Enable interrupt;
    Step2:call function z();
    step3:disable interrupt;
}

interrupt() {
    Step1:Jump Step 3 of function x();
}
```

**Explanation**: Function Z should execute within some time duration so I'm using a timer  interrupt to achieve that timeout. I'm giving step 3 of function x() address in interrupt service routine so that control will come back after particular time duration (jumping is achieved by changing the PC address).

**Hardware**: NEC V850E2 processor, GHS compiler.
**Software**: Embedded C.

Comment: Are you saying that you're using your ISR to "kill" execution of Z(), and restore control to X()?  This is tricky; in general, you need to unwind the stack.  Alternatively, you may want to investigate setjmp and longjmp.

Comment: yeah your understanding is correct..little bit tricky but i have to do that one...

Answer (score 2):

If [GHS compilers](http://www.ghs.com/products/optimizingC++EC++Compilers.html) are very compatible with GCC (as they claim), they might have the GCC [`__builtin_return_address`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Return-Address.html) (but this is not standard, and specific to GCC).

Maybe your target system is supported by a recent GCC? If yes, it could be worth to build GCC from source code.

Otherwise you need to write your own assembly code.

Comment: Sorry..GHS and GCC both are completely different compilers...i cant use that function...