# Getting the return address of a function in C

Tags: c, function, gcc, memory-address, built-in

I have some C code that essentially looks something like

```
double* my_function(double* input) {
    double* output = (double*) malloc(...);
    // Do some stuff to output based on input
    return output;
}
```

Assuming that I have already built an array called *my_var_in*, my main code has something like

```
double* my_var_out = my_function(my_var_in);
```

This creates *new* memory, which *my_var_out* points to; most of the time that's exactly what I want to happen. However, sometimes I just want to *update* the already existing memory. If I write

```
double* my_var = ... ; // allocate and fill my_var as desired
my_var = my_function(my_var);
```

Then I lose the pointer to the previously existing memory since *my_var* now points to the newly allocated memory. I've played around with several different ideas for how to get around this.

1) I know I can get this to work by changing the function style to something like

```
void my_function(double* destination, double* source) {
    // Check if destination == source and update based on this
```

I've previously developed with this style of passing the destination pointer as an input argument and updating it there; it works great functionally, but I like the style of outputting pointers better and want to keep developing with it.

2) Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094024/how-to-know-the-return-address-of-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818282/how-to-find-the-return-address-of-a-function-in-c/), it seems that the **__builtin_return_address** function could be of some use. I think I can use this function to compare the input address with the output address and allocate/update based on that. After reading the documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Return-Address.html), I wrote the following test

```
int* just_testing(int* in) {
    void* ptr = __builtin_return_address(0); // the return address of just_testing
    printf("Input address: %p\n", in);
    printf("From function: %p\n", ptr);

    return in;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int* out = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    out[0] = 2;
    printf("From main before call: %p\n", out);
    out = just_testing(out);
    printf("From main after call: %p\n", out);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the output

```
From main before call: 0x19b2010
Input address: 0x19b2010
From function: 0x4011f1
From main after call: 0x19b2010
```

Unfortunately, the results from **__builtin_return_address** don't match the address of the variable that receives the return from the function, which I did not expect.

Why aren't the addresses the same? I also welcome any constructive suggestions on a different approach besides the two I've listed here.

Comment: That's not what "return address" means, and what you want is impossible, sorry. Just continue passing the destination pointer as an argument; it's quite standard.

Comment: After trying out a few different implementations, it seems like this really is the best way to accomplish what I want. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is to have two separate functions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void compute_inplace(double *data) {
    data[0] *= 2;
}

double *compute_copying(const double *input) {
    double *output = malloc(sizeof *output * N);
    if (output == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memcpy(output, input, sizeof *output * N);
    compute_inplace(output);
    return output;
}
```

Note that the copying function takes its argument as a *pointer to const*, which helps if you accidentally pass a read-only memory area to it.

Comment: I think that the second function should still return the pointer. Apart from that two functions is the best solution because it is known at compile time what the programmer wants.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution could be to have following definition:-

```
double* my_function(double* input, bool alloc)
{
   double* output = input;

   if(alloc)
   {
       //allocate new memory
       double* output = ( double*)malloc(...);
   }
   //else work with input memory

   //do modifications here

   return output;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I just implemented it and included varargs so that it only needs the extra argument if it is updating. Still not as clean as I would like, and there's still a possibility of losing the pointer.